# Determining rotation axis for matrix with complex eigenvectors.

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, 3d, rotations

I'm using Zhang's method to determine the 3D camera parameters from a set of images. When calculating extrinsic parameters for the third image, I get the following matrix.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
0.9848432  &  0.1745697  &  0.1719238 & - 43.812298  \\
  - 0.1734468 &   0.9833136 & - 0.1705526 &   49.196566 \\  
    0.0002832 &   0.0005524 &    0.0000002   & 8870.6728  \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

After calculating the eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of the rotation matrix (the first three columns) I get the following results.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
    0.7082676              &   0.7082676    &           - 0.1934891  \\
  - 0.0034034 + 0.7059357i & - 0.0034034 - 0.7059357i &   0.1344372  \\
    0.0002637 + 0.0003496i  &  0.0002637 - 0.0003496i  &  0.9718481  \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
    0.9840684 + 0.1740798i & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0.9840684 - 0.1740798i &   0  \\
    0  &  0  &  0.0000202    \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

As far as I know, when I get purely real eigenvectors and eigenvalues, the eigenvector associated to $\lambda = 1$ will be the rotation axis (so far that has worked out fine) but when I get complex values I have no idea how to interpret them (I'm not very familiar with complex numbers).

I would really appreciate some help to determine the axis and angle of rotation from such results.

Comment: The complex eigen values should give you the "angle" of rotation. You need find an angle $\theta$ such that $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are the real and imaginary parts of your complex eigen-value.

Comment: Thanks. The eigenvalues do match the sine and cosine of the angle that the image appears to be rotated at, but from the results there seem to be two vectors around which the rotation has been performed, and from what I can see in the image, the rotation has been performed around one axis only. Is that consistent with the matrices I've posted?

Comment: Yes, if you rotate around two different axes, you still get a rotation about another axis. In other words, if you multiply two rotation matrices, you get another rotation matrix.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I interpret complex coordinates in vectors? Those don't make much sense to me.

Comment: No No. the axis of rotation is the eigen-vector corresponds to the only real eigen-value.

Comment: Ok, so the axis of rotation here would be [-0.19, 0.13, 0.97], right? How is the eigenvalue related to the angle? Here it seems to small a value for a significant rotation.